# If two cells match then return the value of a cell that is associated to one of the first two matching cells

Tags: excel-formula

[Picture of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf0I4.png)

I want a formula that search for matches between "Club" from dataset 1 and "Team" from dataset 2.
All the matches found should be assigned the value of the "Rank" that is associated to the match from dataset 2 in a new column, so each "Name" gets a cell with his club-ranking.

My objective is to give each "Name" a column with a ranking for his club.

Possible?

I tried to do it with IFS function, but it's lot of manual work.

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP